# How can i prevent multiple posts to the same page at the same time in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an input search like this:

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" name="searchSchools" id="searchSchools" value="" onKeyUp="searchSchools(this.value)" />
```

As you can se, every time the onKeyUp event is fired i call a function named "searchSchools" where i search schools matching the current value of the input search in PHP and i return them in JSON format, the problem is that if i type fast more than one request is sent to the PHP page and i want to prevent this, i want to send the post request to the page only if there is no other request to the same page made by this function.

Here is the function:

```
function searchSchools(name){
    $.post("search-schools.php", { name: name },
    function(data) {
        //-> Here i do whatever with data returned
    }, 
    "json"
    );
}
```

Comment: Probably a bad idea, since then you'll only ever query for the first character when the user has entered a whole word already - effectively causing a large delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a delay in `$.post`.. Try like below,

```
var timer = null, xhrReq = null;
function searchSchools(name){
    if (timer != null) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if(xhrReq != null) {
           xhrReq.abort(); //to kill all prev request and take the latest
        }

        xhrReq = $.post("search-schools.php", { name: name },
           function(data) {
              //-> Here i do whatever with data returned
           }, 
           "json"
         );
    }, 1000); //will be posted only after 1 second.
}
```

**Edit:** Added `xhr.abort()` to abort any old request and consider only the latest..

Comment: delays are not reliable to tell if an ajax request has completed

Comment: @RabNawazKhan The delay's purpose isn't to tell if the request is completed, it's to not send a request unless the user stops typing in the input. Similar to what jQuery Autocomplete does.

Comment: The result can come back in the wrong order. Relatively unlikely though

Comment: @skarmats True, added `xhr.abort()` to kill old request :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var request;
function searchSchools(name){
    if (!request) {
       request = $.post("search-schools.php", { name: name },
       function(data) {
           request = false;
           //-> Here i do whatever with data returned
       }, 
       "json"
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Semaphores are a lot better than delays. +1

Comment: yes, delays are not reliable to tell if an ajax request has completed :)

Comment: Wouldn't this only request on the first letter instead of after the user is done typing?

Comment: this is an answer for "_i want to send the post request to the page only if there is no other request to the same page made by this function_" - when to call this function is another issue

Comment: I like the idea, but what happens when I type A and then type BCD. while A is still pending from server.. like will my ABCD be ever queried? Will it not simply ignore BCD since A is still pending at server..

Comment: It does directly answer the question, but I don't think it solves the real problem.

Comment: and when will the request be **TRUE**

Comment: @Rab Nawaz Khan: If a variable points to any instance of (inherited) type `Object`, its expression will evaluate to `true` in a boolean context. Thus, if it's `undefined` or `null` the expression will evalute to false

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the behavior I pointed out in my first comment on the OP

I like to approach this kind of problem in a more wasteful manner:

```
var xhr;
function search(term) {
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.abort();
    }

    xhr = $.post(...);
}
```

This makes the basic logic much easier to handle since the success callbacks of aborted requests won't get called and you always get the most current result regarding the actual input.

If you are wary of starting and aborting potentially many request, introduce a throttler on the appropriate key event - thus also achieving a seperation of the concerns.

Give `xhr` the proper context in your script - it is global in this example. You want to avoid that.

EDIT1 - added:

`xhr` is never unset. You might want to do this in in the `complete` handler of the jQuery AJAX settings object.
On the other hand, calling `abort()` on an aborted or completed request is - in effect - a NOP